# Server 2003 Windows 7 Folder redirection issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, folder-redirection

I removed two windows XP machines yesterday and replaced them with Windows 7. I configured their desktop and documents to redirect to a share on Server 2003 R2. Share is \Server1\AdmDocs

Yesterday it was working fine, however, today, when the two machines log in, it says they can't access the share so their desktops are blank. If I restart the machine, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt.

It also seems as if the faster they login after a shutdown, the more likely the issue will occur as if they are logging in too fast for the nic to catch up. If i restart it and wait a few seconds, they will get their desktop and documents redirected.
Server 2003 Windows 7
I tried enabling offline files sync on windows 7 for the desktop and documents, when I did this and logged in, the user was asked for a username and password to access her redirected desktop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I'd try is opening Group Policy Editor, going to "Computer Configuration" -> "Administrative Templates" -> "System" -> "Logon" -> "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon"

There are other folks who have had to go beyond this step but I have not needed to personally:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374350(v=vs.85).aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/393e6042-dea0-4285-9aeb-2ddf50434f6b/windows-7-always-wait-for-the-network-at-computer-startup-and-logon-group-policy

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out! Should i be applying this group policy via the DC or locally on the win 7 workstations?

Comment: I'd try it on one workstations via the Local Policy and if it works/helps then look at creating a GPO to push it out (to a test machine first!)